# Testing topviewcontroller in a navigationcontroller

Tags: swift, xctest

I want to use XCTest to unit test pushing on the stack.

So I perform a

```
XCTAssert(type(of: navigationController.topViewController) is DetailViewController.Type)
```

Which works if and only if I do not have animation enabled when I push the viewController.

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

But within the viewController I want to test I have the animation enabled

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

When the animation is enabled the type is the previous view controller's type.

I tried a sleep, and I tried using XCTWaiter i.e.

```
let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 3.0)
        if result == XCTWaiter.Result.timedOut {
            XCTAssert(type(of: navigationController.topViewController) is DetailViewController.Type)
        } else {
            XCTFail("Delay interrupted")
        }
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me.

How can I test the navigation stack with animation enabled?

Comment: Where does the navigation controller come into existence for your test?

Comment: let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sut!)
//        window.rootViewController = navigationController

Answer (score 4):

First, load your view controller, and put it into a navigation controller. No need for a UIWindow.

```
sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sut)
```

Then have your test trigger whatever is supposed to push the new view controller.

Finally, to get this to register in the UINavigationController, execute the run loop once.

```
RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
```

Then the test can investigate the stack in `navigation.viewControllers`.

Comment: Within the test view controller self.navigationController resolves as nil in this case.

Comment: Try `sut.loadViewIfNeeded()` which I added above